# Interpretting a traceback

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

So I am trying to install tensorflow and I am getting an error.  My question is not about that persay.  I have found a very helpful answer whihc i think will solve my problem here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20690

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\angus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\angus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

  File "C:\Users\angus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\angus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

  File "C:\Users\angus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The last line, from the guide above suggested changing all variables named async to async1 as async is a global keyword now in python.  But what are those other error messages about?  The first two look like some problem initiating an object, then the other one line 58 of pywrap_tensorflow.py its not even clear there is an error.  What does the asterix indicate?  `from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *`

Comment: A traceback generally represents a single error, not multiple ones, but there can be nested exceptions too. This one is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a single error message (SyntaxError in your case) - the traceback shows the code path taken to get to the line where the error occurred.

In this case it's a chain of imports leading to the syntax error starting with iPython interactive shell, importing tensorflow which imports pywrap_tensorflow, etc

The asterisk means import everything from the previously mentioned module or package.